# localstorage not synchronizing from another tab in Edge if value size is over 64k

Tags: internet-explorer, local-storage, size, limit, microsoft-edge

localstorage key & value will not synchronize from another tab or window if the size is over 64k. Is it a bug? localstorage is saved in different place for each window in IE or Edge? Anyone has a idea about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How do you come out the conclusion that *localstorage key & value will not synchronize from another tab or window if the size is over 64k*?

From the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/storage#local-and-session-storage-managers), it only shows a combined limit of storage in Edge:

- **Subdomains**: up to 5 MBs of space
- **Domains**: up to 10 MBs of space
- **Total for all domains**: up to 50 MBs of space

For more information about the max size of localstorage, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values).

For the location of saving localstorage, you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328691/where-does-microsoft-edge-save-localsorage-on-a-computer-under-windows-10). The answer indicates that the localstorage is saved in the below location so I think it's saved in the same place. To find the folder, you should first turn the option on to display the hidden files:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC#!001\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\DOMStore\IS3DHS80

Comment: I have one window to cut picture and save to localstorage and other window display it. It works fine in chrome and firefox. But in Edge and IE, it works fine only for small cut picture. if it is larger than 64k, it doesn't work. I check the localstorage on both windows but the picture is in cut window localstorage, not in the other display window. I was using F12 in Edge and JS, they all show same results.

Comment: The cut picture in cut window localstorage can be much larger. I think it can be up to  5MB or so.

Comment: You could refer to [this thread](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15339542/). The author seems has the same issue as yours. You could try the solution mentioned below: clearing “Cookies and saved website data” from settings in Edge or resetting Edge to see if it solves the issue. If the issue persists it could be better if you share a simple sample which helps reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Yu Zhou!